# JRuby: Background job processing via Sidekiq

Tags: jruby, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker that executes some JRuby code to connect and pull data from a remote server. It works fine by running on terminal:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

But on production I want to run the worker in background by passing `-d` option:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log
```

It doesn't work and returns the following:

```
ObjectSpace is disabled; each_object will only work with Class, pass -X+O to enable
```

Any other option I need to pass in order to run the sidekiq in background ?

Answer (score 1):

even if you enable ObjectSpace it will fail since you can not fork in JRuby.

you can not use the `-d` option, use system alternatives such as `nohup`

Comment: With that `nohup` I want to execute the sidekiq worker even if I close the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use systemd or upstart instead of daemonizing by hand.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#daemonization